# CSS Navigation Bootstrap issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have this navigation here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h1 class="logo"></h1></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <span style="color:#FFF; font-style:italic; line-height:66px; padding-right: 10px; font-size:12px; float:left;">In The Heart Of Niagara's Historic Wine Country</span>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
              <li><a href="amenities.html">Amenities</a></li>
              <li><a href="dining.html">Breakfast and Dining</a></li>
              <li><a href="region.html">Discover Our Region</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

and this looks fine on Chrome and basically everywhere except for IE 11

Here is what it looks like in chrome:

[image]

And here is what it looks like in IE 11

[image]

My issue is, I am unable to reproduce this in my IE 11 but my clients IE 11 looks like the second image. How can I fix this?

Here is the CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    height: 70px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Have you asked your clients what the resolution of their screen is? Five bucks says the nav is being pushed down on their machine because there's less space, not because it's IE11 (unless you had them check in other browsers and it looked OK in those for them).

Comment: Your problem is not with browser compatibility but with responsiveness. This is how it looks on my Firefox: http://oi64.tinypic.com/nn4duu.jpg with a viewport resolution of 1280x838px. And when I resize the window size it creates more and more distortions in the menu texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your file if it follows html5 structure.

1. `<!DOCTYPE html>` - is very critical, current best practice is in the first line of type HTML document.
2. HTML5Shiv - to enable styling of HTML5 elements in versions of Internet Explorer.
3. Bootstrap version - please make sure you are using the latest version of the framework.
4. Compatibility mode IE11 - if you are running compatibility mode, turn it off.

Comment: Here is my doctype `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Silver Birches by the lake: Niagara Bed and Breakfast</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
`

Comment: I tried to navigate to the existing url using IE11 and it looks great. No issues.

Comment: Check your screen resolution maybe it's not supported in bootstrap media queries.